# Why while loop doesn't use the correct variable in second loop?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, while-loop

I'm trying to send 2 files from the download location to the upload location and doing some renaming. But the second file is renamed to the same name as the first file which is unwanted behaviour.

Executed Bash script:

```
        while [[ "$(ls -A "$dowloadlocation/")" ]]; do
                sourceFileNameWithPath=$(ls -t $dowloadlocation/* | tail -1)
                sourceFileName=${sourceFileNameWithPath##*/}
                log "Source file name: $sourceFileName"
                destinationFilename_temp=${destinationFilename/\$filename/$sourceFileName}
                dateTime=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
                destinationFilename=${destinationFilename_temp/\$dateTime/$dateTime}
                log "Destination file name: $destinationFilename"
                if [[ ! "$destinationFilename" =~ $filename ]] && [[ ! "$destinationFilename" =~ $dateTime ]] ; then
                        mv -f --backup=numbered $filename $uploadlocation/$destinationFilename
                else
                        mv -f --backup=numbered $sourceFileNameWithPath $uploadlocation/$destinationFilename
                fi
        done
```

Output:

```
Fri Jun  9 16:26:39 CEST 2023: Destination file name: $filename_$dateTime.csv
Fri Jun  9 16:26:39 CEST 2023: Moving downloads from downloadfolder to uploadfolder
Fri Jun  9 16:26:39 CEST 2023: Source file name: TEST123
Fri Jun  9 16:26:39 CEST 2023: Destination file name: TEST123_202306091626.csv
Fri Jun  9 16:26:39 CEST 2023: Source file name: TEST
Fri Jun  9 16:26:39 CEST 2023: Destination file name: TEST123_202306091626.csv
```

Expected output:

```
Fri Jun  9 16:26:39 CEST 2023: Destination file name: $filename_$dateTime.csv
Fri Jun  9 16:26:39 CEST 2023: Moving downloads from downloadfolder to uploadfolder
Fri Jun  9 16:26:39 CEST 2023: Source file name: TEST123
Fri Jun  9 16:26:39 CEST 2023: Destination file name: TEST123_202306091626.csv
Fri Jun  9 16:26:39 CEST 2023: Source file name: TEST
Fri Jun  9 16:26:39 CEST 2023: Destination file name: TEST_202306091626.csv
```

Comment: I think you meant something like `for fileName in $(ls -A "$downloadLocation/")`, not `while`. Note that all of this code will break if a path contains spaces.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Please add a valid shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all the recommendations made there.

Comment: Or better `for filename in "$downloadLocation/"*`

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, you'll see the commands as they're executed. This should help understand why it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd structure.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

downloadLocation=/tmp/from
uploadLocation=/tmp/to
dateTime=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)

for fname in $downloadLocation/*; do
    bname=`basename $fname`
    uploadName=$uploadLocation/$dateTime/$bname
    echo mv $fname $uploadName
done
```

As some of the commenters have said, parsing the output of ls is problematic. You could do this or use `find` instead. I haven't tested this if your filenames have spaces, which is why you might need to use find.

Comment: your code would have no problem with spaces in filenames if you quoted your variable use properly. shellcheck can advise